# JQuery function call from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 js files and I need to call a function in one file from the other file.

```
(function ($) {
    function sendMail(subject, message) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: '',
            headers: {'': getCookie('')},
            data: {'subject': subject, 'message': message},
            success: function (data) {},
            error: function (data) {}
        });
    }
})($v1);
```

And I need to call function **sendMessage** from following file:

```
(function ($) {
    $('#post-form').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#submit-btn').attr('disabled', 'true');
        setTimeout(function () {
           $('#submit-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
        }, 1500);
        sendMail($('#subject').val(), $('#text').val())
    });
})($v1);
```

How do I do that?

Comment: first create the function sendMail and then call it. No need to define it inside an anonymous function.

Comment: put two file links  in your  a html file ex : footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sendMail function is trapped within it's own scope and cannot escape on it's own. You need to escape the constraints from the local scope, so you need to attach it to a "global" object.

So you can make it a jQuery plugin via `$.fn.`, or attach it to the window object, or do both to get in the global scope.
Making it a jQuery plugin really only makes sense if you actually get the data from the object you're calling it from, but there's no reason at all why you can't do it like this.

```
(function ($) {
    window.sendMail = $.fn.sendMail = function(subject, message) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: '',
            headers: {'': getCookie('')},
            data: {'subject': subject, 'message': message},
            success: function (data) {},
            error: function (data) {}
        });
    }
})($v1);

(function ($) {
    $('#post-form').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $btn = $('#submit-btn');
        $btn.attr('disabled', 'true');
        setTimeout(function () {
           $btn.removeAttr('disabled');
        }, 1500);

        // now you can choose which to use.
        $btn.sendMail($('#subject').val(), $('#text').val())
        //or
        window.sendMail($('#subject').val(), $('#text').val())
    });
})($v1);
```

Comment: Why not provide a callback to the currently useless success and error functions?

Comment: Because that's not what OP asked, I assume op deleted the useless content to keep it minimal